# Help with store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need help with the following sp. Couldnt solve it really.
I have 2 columns in a table:
1. Parent
2. Child

I need to create a sp using rownum that will create a new table with a given param (level num) that will display the connection between the parent and son, or grandfather & grandson, etc...

For instance:

```
Parent | Child
2         4
4         6
```

the sp will return with a given level of 1 the same table, but if I hand it level 2 (grandfather<-> grandson) it will show:

```
Parent | Child
2        6
```

How can I do that?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE     @level INT
SET         @level = 3

DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
  parent    INT, 
  child     INT
)

DECLARE @result TABLE
(
  parent    INT, 
  child     INT
)

INSERT INTO     @result
SELECT * FROM   testing

WHILE @level > 1
BEGIN
    SET @level = @level - 1
    DELETE  @temp

    INSERT INTO @temp
    SELECT t.parent, r.child
    FROM testing t
    INNER JOIN @result r
        ON t.child = r.parent

    DELETE @result

    INSERT INTO @result
    SELECT * FROM @temp
END

SELECT * FROM @result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code using a recursive cte that does what I believe it is you want.

```
-- Sample data
declare @T table (ID int, ParentID int)
insert into @T values
(1, null),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 3),
  (6, 1),
(7, null),
  (8, 7),
    (9, 8),
      (10, 9)

-- The level you want
declare @Level int = 2

-- recursive cte
;with cte as
(
  select
    ID,
    ParentID,
    0 as lvl
  from @T
  where ParentID is null
  union all
  select
    T.ID,
    T.ParentID,
    C.lvl+1 as lvl
  from @T as T
    inner join cte as C
      on T.ParentID = C.ID
  where C.lvl < @Level    
)
select *
from cte
where lvl = @Level
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto join. For level 2:

```
SELECT  
    p.Parent
    ,c.Child
FROM 
    Table_1 p
JOIN Table_1 c 
    ON p.Child = c.Parent
```

level 3:

```
SELECT 
    g.Parent
    ,c.Child
FROM 
    Table_1 g
JOIN Table_1 p
    ON g.Child = p.Parent
JOIN Table_1 c 
    ON p.Child = c.Parent
```

If you need solution for arbitrary level, try to generate [dinamic sql](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1160) based on level.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetConnected
    @level INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT t0.Parent, t' + CAST(@level AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.Child FROM Table_1 t0 '

    DECLARE @counter INT
    SET @counter = 0

    WHILE @counter < @level
    BEGIN   
        SET @sql = @sql + 'JOIN Table_1 t' + CAST(@counter + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' ON t' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.Child = t' + CAST(@counter + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.Parent '
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END

    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide more details?

Comment: I need to use rownum so when its 0 i will know no more children are available to scan - and I can quite the loop

Comment: If you are talking about my store procedure, no. Iterations don't get  'real' data, just create sql joins. When you call EXEC data is retrieved.

Comment: Why do you need to use rownum?

Answer (score 0):

This solution, for which I've shamelessly borrowed Mikael's sample data definition, shows all the relations represented, building pairs not only from the top level (parentless) items, but also from the lower level ones. The author of the question didn't specify whether it should be one way or the other.

```
/* Sample data */
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, ParentID int);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, NULL),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
    (4, 3),
    (5, 3),
  (6, 1),
(7, NULL),
  (8, 7),
    (9, 8),
      (10, 9);

/* The level you want */
DECLARE @Level int;
SET @Level = 2;

/* The query */
WITH recur AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    AncestorID = ParentID,
    Level = CASE WHEN ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM @T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    r.ID,
    t.AncestorID,
    Level = r.Level + 1
  FROM @T t
    INNER JOIN recur r ON t.ID = r.AncestorID
  WHERE r.Level < @Level
)
SELECT ID, ParentID
FROM recur
WHERE Level = @Level
  AND (@Level = 0 OR ParentID IS NOT NULL)
```

For the given `@Level` value of `2` the result will be:

```
ID          AncestorID  Level
----------- ----------- -----------
10          8           2
9           7           2
5           1           2
4           1           2
```